# Double column Highcharts with drilldown

Tags: charts, highcharts, drilldown

I am using Highcharts for generating a two column bar graph. Means for each day I am showing the number of downloads and number of signups. Now I need to have a drilldown, which shows up the hourly data. The Highcharts docs is showing an example for Signle column by specifying the y value. But as I am showing stached bar, I have two y values for the same date. The code I am using is as follows :

```
series: [{
 name    : 'Signups,
 color   : '#0066FF',
 data    : <?=$series_1?>, //data in JSON format from PHP
 drilldown: true                       
 }, {
 name    : 'Downloads',
 color   : '#E81531',
 data    : <?=$series_2?>, //data in JSON format from PHP
 drilldown: true

}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for you for drilldown with two series, with `stacking: 'normal'`: http://jsfiddle.net/6zYmJ/10/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Things2',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals2',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals2'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits2',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits2'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars2',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars2'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        },{
            id: 'animals2',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits2',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars2',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawel. But is there any possibility that I can show it as two bars instead of putting one on top of the other.. ?

Comment: You need to disable stacking, calculate values on your own and then use that values for series.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Pawel Response-

Just replace in plotOptions with this value

column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
,